# Is a seamigly immutable struct considered immutable?

Tags: python, function

I'm new with functional programming but experienced enough with code to sense a false good idea/antipattern, and that may be the case:
I'm not exactly sure what "immutability" means. Does the state of an object has to be frozen ? Or should the object ONLY behave as such ? In my case, I can make my object immutable OR implement some lazy resolving/cache. From an external point of view nothing should behave differently in any way. Yet the state of my object WILL change.

I can post code if you want me to but the questions seems not language specific enough to do, but I'm coding in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: An “immutable” object prohibits sanctioned mutations: eg. there are no setters or methods that update the state. A mutable object may still be “effectively immutable” based on usage. Just as in even a strongly typed language like C#, bypassing the contract as for example with reflection, should not imply an object is not “immutable”.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a *mutable* object can be changed after it is created, and an *immutable* object can’t.

 Python handles mutable and immutable objects differently.

 Specifically for **Python**, I found an interesting post [on medium.com](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)

Comment: That article contains suspect information along with good information. For starters, Python treats mutable and immutable objects the same - it is simply that an immutable object cannot be changed and thus all variable updates require a new object to be assigned in the immutable case, naught else.

Comment: I'm familiar with python immutability, rather than implementation, my question was more on the conceptual/pattern aspect, specifically in respect of functional programming.